# Can gitlab be installed with Cherokee web server?

Tags: git, webserver, ruby

I've looked all over and can't figure out you could use Cherokee instead of Apache or Nginx for gitlab. I'd rather not run multiple webservers (and imagine that they could conflict anyway). I'm giving this a shot on Ubuntu Server 12.10.

For the record, I've already installed gitlab with [this guide](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/5-4-stable/doc/install/installation.md) up to the Nginx section (with all default settings other than passwords, email addresses, and hostname). I'd like to install gitlab at git.mydomain.com and I would prefer for the local server files to be located at /var/www/git.mydomain.com, as I keep all of my domains under /var/www/.

Comment: Have you actually tried looking at the provided nginx config and replicate that config in Cherokee?

Comment: @Mxx [Here's a pastebin of that config](http://pastebin.com/rBygvGZZ). Doesn't seem like there's anything special in there, unless I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Even though I never installed Gitlab and have very little experience with Cherokee, it seem like this nginx is configured to talk to gitlab's app server over unix sockets(`upstream` section). Configure your Cherokee the same way...

Comment: @Mxx I honestly have no idea whatsoever of how I would do that. Searching for "cherokee server upstream" yields no results. I tried putting a header with name 'upstream' and the value of the path, but that didn't work either. Any tips of where I might even need to look?